# Proving that if $\sum a_n$ converges that $\sum a_n^2$ converges too (if $\sum a_n >0$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, absolute-convergence

We assume that $a_n >0$ for all $n\geq 0$. This is my proof so far:

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then the limit of the sequence $\sum a_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity is $0$ and so for any $\epsilon>0$ there's an corresponding $N$ such that:

$0<|a_n-0|< \epsilon$ if $n>N$

If $\epsilon=1$, we can say $0<|a_n^2|<|a_n|<\epsilon$ and then by comparison $\sum a_n^2$ is convergent too.

I'm just stuck on the part where epsilon would be bigger than 1? How could I include that in my proof? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on your condition, either [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424622/convergence-of-sum-a-n-sum-a-n2-and-sum-a-n4) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436752/convergence-of-a-series-with-squared-terms) is a duplicate

Comment: This question seems fine for me, I don't know why it was downvotes. I demand downvoter to comeback and write its reason for downvote. also I demand downvoter to pay attention to this question and remove their downvote if an edit is made.

Comment: @LuisFelipe The sentence $\sum a_n >0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ is unclear, that's why the answerers below has to guess the conditions. How is this post fine?

Comment: @ArcticChar its clear to me, if you had read more than 1 real analysis book you should know that this means that series converges.

Comment: Well you are wrong... $\sum a_n >0$ means that the series converges and the limit is positive. But $\sum a_n >0$ for $n\ge 0$ is unclear. The answer-ers below think that it might mean "$a_n >0$ for all $n\ge 0$". @LuisFelipe

Comment: @Luis Felipe. Your comment to ArcticChar is rude and of course wrong. For positive series $\sum a_n < +\infty$ means convergence, not $\sum a_n >0$. Name, please, exactly book and page where you find it.

Comment: Well, I didn't expect my question would cause so much controversy! Thank you @ArcticChar, I checked both links out (didn't come across them earlier when googling), but they don't really answer the part I am confused about. That is, what if epsilon >1? Then you can't say a_n^2 is bigger than a_n, right? I was hoping someone could clarify that, because I just don't understand that. Also, I get what you mean with it being unclear! That was a stupid oversight on my behalf, I'll change it right now! What I meant is that∑a_n converged and that all a_n are positive

Comment: @LuisFelipe Please tell me in which real analysis book you saw the definition of "$\sum a_n > 0$ for all $n$".

Comment: obviusly, the part $n\ge0$ is more information than you need because $n\in\mathbb{N}$. You can see any book from Elon Lages Lima, even mathematics 3 from Armando Venero.

Comment: @LuisFelipe It seems you still don't understand what is the problem. The statement $\sum a_n >0$ does not depend on $n$. So both "$\sum a_n >0$ for all $n \ge 0$" and "$\sum a_n >0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ do not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you just assume that $\sum a_n > 0$, then the result is not true. For example a counterexample is given by
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

However, if the hypothesis is that $a_n > 0$, then the fact that $\sum a_n$ converges implies that $a_n$ tends to $0$, so in particular,
$$a_n^2=o(a_n)$$

so by comparison, $\sum a_n^2$ also converges.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a_n\ge0$, there is an $N$ such that

$$\forall n>N\implies 0\le a_n\le1$$ which implies $$0\le a_n^2\le a_n\le1$$ and by squeezing the sum of squares converges.

Comment: I get that, but what if we take an epsilon bigger than 1, for example 5, then we can't just say that a_n > a_n^2, right?

Comment: @Anonymmy: right, but that does not matter. We don't care about these terms.

Comment: could you maybe explain why not?

Comment: @Anonymmy: because they bring a finite contribution to the sum.